# What happens when intel HLE fails to commit?

Tags: c, assembly, transactions, x86, intel-tsx

From the [Intel Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf):

> The processor attempts to commit the HLE execution, when [...].
>
> **If execution cannot commit atomically, then execution transitions to a non-transactional execution without elision as if the first instruction did not have an `XAQUIRE` prefix.**

Did I read that correctly? Basically "try to do it transactionally, but if you can't, I don't care if you do it anyway"?

If so, what's the point in having the `HLE` extension at all if it may randomly decide to behave as if it didn't exist?

Comment: The manual emphasizes that this extension is _only_ for performance reasons, there is no functional difference if it is used or not.

Comment: @Ctx I had not caught that. Thank you. Want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: If it fails to commit, it rolls everything back and re-runs the code, ignoring the `XAQUIRE` prefix the 2nd time.  If you use RTM instead of HLE, abort results in a jump to the address given to `xbegin`, where you can choose what happens.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898325/does-an-aborted-xbegin-transaction-restore-the-stack-context-that-existed-at-the for a trivial example that retries)