# x86 assembly help: Is there a general rule for what the value of rax is?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

So I'm trying to figure out what this function does, but I'm a little puzzled by this instruction sequence:

```
mov    -0x4(%rsp),%eax
lea    0x0(,%rax,8),%edx
```

There isn't a mention of rax within the function before that.
What would be the value within the rax register--is it just the top of the stack?

The previous line was `mov    -0x4(%rsp),%eax`, so is it just whatever's in `eax`?

Comment: `eax` is the low 32 bits of `rax` and writing to `eax` clears the top 32 bits. So yeah, `rax` has the 32 bit value from memory at address `rsp-4` zero extended to 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

"general rule"?  No, there can't be a general rule other than tautologies (like "whatever you last put in it, implicitly or explicitly") or very detailed rules that cover everything that implicitly uses `rax`, like:

- function return value in most calling conventions
- low half of a full-multiply result (one-operand `mul` or `imul`).
- quotient after `div` / `idiv`
- low half of the 64b or 128b load result from [`cmpxchg8b` / `cmpxchg16b`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG8B:CMPXCHG16B.html)
- `xlatb` / `lodsb/w/d/q` result
- the abort info [after an aborted Transactional Memory operation (RTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898325/does-an-aborted-xbegin-transaction-restore-the-stack-context-that-existed-at-the)
- Part of a CPUID result
- Probably some other implicit EAX/RAX uses that I'm forgetting.

Writing eax always zero-extends into rax ([Why do most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register)), but writing AL, AH, or AX merge with the old value of RAX.